# Dependent types: enforcing global properties in inductive types

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I have the following inductive type `MyVec`:

```
import Data.Vect

data MyVec: {k: Nat} -> Vect k Nat -> Type where
  Nil: MyVec []
  (::): {k, n: Nat} -> {v: Vect k Nat} -> Vect n Nat -> MyVec v -> MyVec (n :: v)

-- example:
val: MyVec [3,2,3]
val = [[2,1,2], [0,2], [1,1,0]]
```

That is, the type specifies the lengths of all vectors inside a `MyVec`.

The problem is, `val` will have `k = 3` (`k` is the number of vectors inside a `MyVec`), but the ctor `::` does not know this fact. It will first build a `MyVec` with `k = 1`, then with `2`, and finally with `3`. This makes it impossible to define constraints based on the final shape of the value.

For example, I cannot constrain the values to be strictly less than `k`. Accepting `Vect`s of `Fin (S k)` instead of `Vect`s of `Nat` would rule out some valid values, because the last vectors (the first inserted by the ctor) would "know" a smaller value of `k`, and thus a stricter contraint.

Or, another example, I cannot enforce the following constraint: *the vector at position i cannot contain the number i*. Because the final position of a vector in the container is not known to the ctor (it would be automatically known if the final value of k was known).

So the question is, how can I enforce such global properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to do it, both of which may require tracking additional information in order to check the property.

### Enforcing properties in the `data` definition

#### Enforcing all elements `< k`

> I cannot constrain the values to be strictly less than `k`. Accepting `Vect`s of `Fin (S k)` instead of `Vect`s of `Nat` would rule out some valid values...

You are right that simply changing the definition of `MyVect` to have `Vect n (Fin (S k))` in it would not be correct.

However, it is not too hard to fix this by generalizing `MyVect` to be polymorphic, as follows.

```
data MyVec: (A : Type) -> {k: Nat} -> Vect k Nat -> Type where
  Nil: {A : Type} -> MyVec A []
  (::): {A : Type} -> {k, n: Nat} -> {v: Vect k Nat} -> Vect n A -> MyVec A v -> MyVec A (n :: v)

val : MyVec (Fin 3) [3,2,3]
val = [[2,1,2], [0,2], [1,1,0]]
```

The key to this solution is separating the type of the vector from `k` in the definition of `MyVec`, and then, at top level, using the "global value of `k` to constrain the type of vector elements.

#### Enforcing vector at position `i` does not contain `i`

> I cannot enforce that the vector at position i cannot contain the number i because the final position of a vector in the container is not known to the constructor.

Again, the solution is to generalize the `data` definition to keep track of the necessary information. In this case, we'd like to keep track of what the current position in the *final* value will be. I call this `index`. I then generalize `A` to be passed the current index. Finally, at top level, I pass in a predicate enforcing that the value does not equal the index.

```
data MyVec': (A : Nat -> Type) -> (index : Nat) -> {k: Nat} -> Vect k Nat -> Type where
  Nil: {A : Nat -> Type} -> {index : Nat} -> MyVec' A index []
  (::): {A : Nat -> Type} -> {k, n, index: Nat} -> {v: Vect k Nat} ->
        Vect n (A index) -> MyVec' A (S index) v -> MyVec' A index (n :: v)

val : MyVec' (\n => (m : Nat ** (n == m = False))) 0 [3,2,3]
val = [[(2 ** Refl),(1 ** Refl),(2 ** Refl)], [(0 ** Refl),(2 ** Refl)], [(1 ** Refl),(1 ** Refl),(0 ** Refl)]]
```

### Enforcing properties after the fact

Another, sometimes simpler way to do it, is to *not* enforce the property immediately in the `data` definition, but to write a predicate after the fact.

#### Enforcing all elements `< k`

For example, we can write a predicate that checks whether all elements of all vectors are `< k`, and then assert that our value has this property.

```
wf : (final_length : Nat) -> {k : Nat} -> {v : Vect k Nat} -> MyVec v -> Bool
wf final_length [] = True
wf final_length (v :: mv) = isNothing (find (\x => x >= final_length) v) && wf final_length mv

val : (mv : MyVec [3,2,3] ** wf 3 mv = True)
val = ([[2,1,2], [0,2], [1,1,0]] ** Refl)
```

#### Enforcing vector at position `i` does not contain `i`

Again, we can express the property by checking it, and then asserting that the value has the property.

```
wf : (index : Nat) -> {k : Nat} -> {v : Vect k Nat} -> MyVec v -> Bool
wf index [] = True
wf index (v :: mv) = isNothing (find (\x => x == index) v) && wf (S index) mv

val : (mv : MyVec [3,2,3] ** wf 0 mv = True)
val = ([[2,1,2], [0,2], [1,1,0]] ** Refl)
```